# Why is this a Dynkin System?

Tags: measure-theory

We have $n$ $\pi$-systems $\mathcal{C}_1, \dotsc, \mathcal{C}_n$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},P)$ with $\Omega \in \mathcal{C}_i$ for all $i$ and

$$P[C_1 \cap \dotsc \cap C_n] = P[C_1] \dotsb P[C_n]$$

for all $C_i \in \mathcal{C}_i$, $i \geq 1$.

Now consider $\mathcal{D}:=\{D \in \mathcal{A} \colon P[D \cap C_2 \cap \dotsc \cap C_n] = P[D] P[C_2] \dotsb P[C_n]\}$.

We want to show that it is a Dynkin system.

It is clear that $\Omega \in \mathcal{C}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{D}$.

But why does it hold that $P[A^c  \cap C_2 \cap \dotsc \cap C_n] = P[A^c] P[C_2] \dotsb P[C_n]$ for $A \in \mathcal{D}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following disjoint union:
$$
C_2 \cap \cdots \cap C_n
= (A \cap C_2 \cap \cdots \cap C_n)
\cup (A^c \cap C_2 \cap \cdots \cap C_n).
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{aligned}
P[A^c \cap C_2 \cap \cdots \cap C_n]
&= P[C_2 \cap \cdots \cap C_n]
- P[A \cap C_2 \cap \cdots \cap C_n] \\
&= P[C_2]\cdots P[C_n]
- P[A]P[C_2]\cdots P[C_n] \\
&= (1 - P[A])P[C_2]\cdots P[C_n] \\
&= P[A^c]P[C_2]\cdots P[C_n].
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I guess you should start with 2 instead of 1 with the indices? But I get the proof idea. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user136457 whoops, yes, of course you're right! I didn't read the question carefully enough.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Just one minor thing left: You use in the second line that $P[C_2 \cap \dotsc \cap C_n] $ factorizes. 

Actually you can only use this because $\Omega$ is in $\mathcal{D}$, so you add $\Omega$ to the intersection and apply the property that holds for all elements in $\mathcal{D}$. Is this true?

Comment: @user136457 Yes, I used the fact that $\Omega \in \mathcal{C_1} \subseteq \mathcal{D}$.